# Java error when unpluggin device from COM port

Tags: java, serial-port, inputstream, rxtx

i'm using rxtx to connect to a serial port. Everything works fine but there is a problem I can't solve.

Once connected and reading, there is the possibility that the users unplugs the device (yes… users…). If this happens I get the following error:

[image]

I don’t get an exception, it just kills java se (java.exe). If I’d get an exception, I’d just act accordingly, but in this scenario, my app stops working and is closed.

I use InputStream to read from de serial port. 
InputStream input = serialPort.getInputStream();

I think the problem is that the stream is open and it doesn´t detect when the device is closed. It happens when I read by this line:
byte singleData = (byte) input.read();

I couldn’t find any method that would help me to test the state prior reading. 
Even if I don´t read (or work with the InputStream), after a few seconds the error arises anyway (I think someone is trying to close de input or something).

How can I get this event (device unplugged)? How should I close the port and the input stream?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not post links to external information.  Links go bad.  Your question should be self-contained, so it retains its value in the future.  The error you are seeing is likely in the C code that underlies the Java library (via JNI).  This is probably a bug in RXTX, so the best place to get help would probably be the [RXTX Github Site](https://github.com/rxtx/rxtx).

Comment: Jim, thanks for your reply. Stackoverflow didn't let me post the image, just gave me this option. I'll search your link. I leave this question anyway, hoping someone can help me.

Answer (score -2):

I prefer jssc library rather than rxtx. You can use try...catch block to avoid the crush.

Comment: Try/catch what exactly?

Comment: using a try/catch block you can do the serial port event tasks, in order to read data from port or write data to port. The try block will have the code for reading or writing data. And the catch block will handle the exceptions like interruption of reading or writing data so that the program does not crash. Moreover you can make the program more efficient by using a thread along with try/catch which will monitor if the serial port is connected or not, if it is disconnected for some reasons or not. And it won't let the program crash.

(seeking apology for late reply as I was not in contact)